# what's the difference between these 2 ways of declaring objects in java?

Tags: java

```
Display dis;
```

and

```
Display dis = new Display();
```

what exactly these two statements do?
I've tried them both but can't seem to know the difference. 
P.S. noob coder here

Comment: first one is not even initialized and has `null` value

Comment: @m.antkowicz Only if declared as field, not if declared as local variable.

Comment: This is a really basic question. You should probably first do a java tutorial or some lessons to understand the fundamentals. You will get a bunch of correct anwers here, some are really detailed. But you would learn java way faster by just doing a tutorial or a lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other programming languages like C++, it is not sufficient to declare a variable to have an actual object assigned to it:

```
Display dis; // dis == null
```

You need to instantiate an object with

```
dis = new Display(); // dis now contains a reference to a new Display instance
```

You can declare a variable and assign a reference to a new instance at the same time, if you like:

```
Display dis = new Display();
```

*(Note: in Java it is customary to start class names with an uppercase letter)*

Answer (score 0):

```
Display dis;
```

The above statement is a *declaration of a reference* of type `Display`. There is no object created here.

---

```
Display dis = new Display();
```

This statement is a *instantiation of an Object* of type `Display`.

---

The two statements are not the same at all. The second statement creates an object using the `new` operator and assigns the created object to the reference `dis` so that you can perform operations on the object using `dis`.

For example:

```
dis.show();
```

Without the creation of the object you will not be able to perform the above operation.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `dis = new display();` a new `Display` object is created in memory and it's reference is put under `dis`. When you're just doing `Display dis` a place in the stack is reserved to the variable, but there's `null` there and not a "real" object.